# latitude and longitude values are round about 100 meter far from my location

Tags: android, gps, location

I am getting a diffrent latitude and longitude when i click the button but all are round about values to the exact location where i am. i saw all these location on google map. i want exact latitude and longitude that point me on google map accuratly where i am.

In this app there is 1 MainActivity and 1 service

This is code of MainActivity

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tvLat, tvLon;
Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLat);
    tvLon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLon);
    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled    
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                tvLat.setText("Latitude: " + Double.toString(latitude)+ "");
                tvLon.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude)+ "");

                String url = "http://waheed.comoj.com/LocationSaver.php?lat=" +
                latitude + "&lon=" + longitude;

                  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                  startActivity(i);

            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

This is code of Service

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 1 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 500 * 60 * 1; // (1/2) minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) 
        mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Either GPS or Network or both are 
            disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        Log.d("Network Lat", Double.toString(latitude));
                        Log.d("Network Lon", Double.toString(longitude));
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location is null", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "locationManager is 
                        null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                   MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = 
                    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            Log.d("GPS Lat", Double.toString(latitude));
                            Log.d("GPS Lon", Double.toString(longitude));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }      
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To getting fine locations you can use a nice library named [LittleFluffy](https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/)

also google recommended strategies for getting most accurate location in : [location strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Comment: Arash, i dont know about this library. Kindly guide me a little bit

Comment: @MKBukhari : the way of how doing LittleFluffy is not very simple to write some codes and get locations ready to use, i think the best reference to embed littlefluffy in your code is reading documentation in the link carefully. and if you have problems, you can take apart your problems in small questions and post it here someone will help you , good luck.

Comment: can you guide me regarding my above code? can you fix it

Comment: my actual problem is that i m sitting in my office and click the button in my app to display latitude and longitude in Text Views. but after clicking the button it displays latitude and longitude of the location which is round about 10 meter far from my office

Comment: @MKBukhari : i think you need to read google documentation about how location Manager Works, Gps locations (Gps provider,Network Provider) cannot be 100% accurate. you can just check accuracy of location and just get most near location to your current location. littlefluffy has a sample application which did same as you . plz take a look.